# Convergence of $\sum\frac{a_n}{b_n} $ and $ \sum (\frac{a_n}{b_n})^2 $ implies convergence of $ \sum\frac{a_n}{a_n+b_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n,b_n\in \mathbb R$ such that for each $n$ we have $(a_n+b_n)b_n\neq 0$ and both the series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ and $\sum_1^\infty (\frac{a_n}{b_n})^2$ convergent then prove $\sum_1^\infty\frac{a_n}{a_n+b_n}$ is convergent.

I tried writing $\frac{a_n}{a_n+b_n}$ like $\frac{\frac{a_n}{b_n}}{\frac{a_n}{b_n}+1}$ but I don't think if this is enough and I don't know how $(\frac{a_n}{b_n})^2$ appears.

Comment: Because ...? And therefore ... ? Why ... ? Please provide context.